# State modified in discrete callback is not reflected in continuous callback

Tags: drake

```
class TestSystem(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, num_internal_bodies, internal_object_list):
        self.dummy_idx = self.DeclareDiscreteState(1)

        self.spatial_forces_output_port = self.DeclareAbstractOutputPort(
            "spatial_forces_output", lambda: forces_cls(),
            self.DoCalcAbstractOutput
        )

        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=2e-3,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.0,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.


    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        context.get_mutable_discrete_state(self.dummy_idx).set_value([1.0])


    def DoCalcAbstractOutput(self, context, spatial_out):
        is_on = context.get_mutable_discrete_state(self.dummy_idx).value()
```

It is very surprising to me that in the above logic, the discrete state is not reflected properly in DoCalcAbstractOutput.

If I print "is_on" I see that the value is 0.0, instead of 1.0 like expected.

I don't understand how this can be happening. At least it seems an error should be raised - but it just silently fails, in the sense that the self.dummy_idx state in DoCalcAbstractOutput has no knowledge of what happened in Update. What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the wrong state

```
    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        context.get_mutable_discrete_state(self.dummy_idx).set_value([1.0])
```

should be, e.g.

```
    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        discrete_state.get_mutable_vector(self.dummy_idx).set_value([1.0])
```

The intention is that context is const -- a snapshot of the current context, and discrete_state is the value you write into to make the change.
(Your bug wouldn't happen in C++, because the context would actually be `const` in this method. When python discards the constness, it makes it more confusing.)

Here is a full update of your example (which had an number of small issues)

```
from pydrake.all import LeafSystem, List, Simulator, Value, ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce

class TestSystem(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.dummy_idx = self.DeclareDiscreteState(1)

        forces_cls = Value[List[ExternallyAppliedSpatialForce]]
        self.DeclareAbstractOutputPort(
            "spatial_forces_vector",
            lambda: forces_cls(),
            self.DoCalcAbstractOutput)

        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=1,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.0,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.


    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        discrete_state.get_mutable_vector(self.dummy_idx).set_value([1.0])


    def DoCalcAbstractOutput(self, context, spatial_out):
        print(context.get_discrete_state(self.dummy_idx).value())
        

system = TestSystem()
simulator = Simulator(system)
context = simulator.get_context()

system.get_output_port().Eval(context)
simulator.AdvanceTo(2)
system.get_output_port().Eval(context)
```

the output is

```
[0.]
[1.]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the discrete_state also does not work.

Comment: Would there be any plan to raise errors when using the context erroneously or other scenarios like this? I feel like a lot more errors and exception checking could help a lot with self-discovery and self-learning of Drake.

Comment: using the discrete_state does work.  i've updated my answer with a full example.

Comment: BTW context should be "const" in DoCalcAbstractOutput() also, so get_discrete_state() would be better there rather than get_mutable_discrete_state().